# FTP to legacy IBM i with Filezilla

Tags: ibm-midrange

I want to FTP into IBM i (AS400) directly to "legacy file system".

Some sites talks about adding these lines to appropriate  section.

```
<PostLoginCommands>         
  <Command>site namefmt 1</Command>
  <Command>site listfmt 1</Command>
  <Command>cwd /QSYS.LIB/USERLIB.LIB </Command>
  <Command>TYPE A</Command>
</PostLoginCommands>
```

I found setup file in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\FileZilla
I know that this is correct file because when I deleted contents Filezilla lost setup menu.

Unfortunately this does not work for me. Filezilla seems to ignore the section entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Check CHGFTPA command on IBMi.
In Filezilla, put /QSYS.LIB/TEMP.LIB or something like that in the remote directory.

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're missing the `QOUTE`

This works for me...

```
        <PostLoginCommands>
            <Command>qoute site namefmt 1</Command>
            <Command>qoute site listfmt 1</Command>
            <Command>cwd /QSYS.LIB/MYLIB.LIB</Command>
        </PostLoginCommands>
```

Note that this goes into the `sitemanager.xml` file, not sure if that's the "setup file" you're talking about.

So you'd need to add an entry for your IBM i via the site manager utility within FileZilla, close FileZilla, and edit the entry in `sitemanager.xml` adding the commands above after the `<port>21</port>` line.  Save and restart FileZilla and use the site manager utility to connect to your system.